# Dailymotion Player is not Working in UIWebview Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiwebview

I've written the following code in Xcode 9.  The ID variable comes from another viewcontroller of mine, via a segue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ID" {

        if let indexPath = self.tblview.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let controller = segue.destination as! DViewController
            let value = arrRes[indexPath.row]
            controller.videoId = value["id"] as! String        
        }   
    }
    class DViewController : UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var Views: UIWebView!
        var ID : String!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let url = URL(string: "https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/\(ID)?sharing-enable=0&ui-logo=0&endscreen-enable=0&autoplay=1")
            Views.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
            Views.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Page not found.  The page you're looking for is ... restricted ...

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because the page isn't found.  Try going to that page in a browser.  The [link you put in your code](https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video//(ID)?sharing-enable=0&ui-logo=0&endscreen-enable=0&autoplay=1) returns a `404` page, in other words, it does not go anywhere meaningful.  Your code looks fine; it's the link that is broken.

[image]

Before you start trying to debug your code, try to think of the simplest possible explanation of why it might not be working.  Usually the simplest explanation is the correct explanation.  In this case, the error message said it all - the page couldn't be found.  There's nothing there.